# Having to cancel and resent requests b/c of client-side timeouts

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, error, failed-transaction, alchemy-sdk

Curious how often people are running into this issue? Aka either you never end up receiving a response OR, you have keep sending requests over and over to the node which is expensive and time-consuming. If you do run into this issue, wondering how you solve it?

One solution I've found is the [Alchemy ethers.js SDK](https://github.com/alchemyplatform/alchemy-sdk-js/?a=18798bffa0) -- it automatically retries for you if requests fails.